# why top gives cpu percents more than 100%

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, top

see below statistics by "top -u steve", something is wrong with top?

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND 
 3490 steve     20   0 10444  312  248 R  114  0.0  23:33.22 test2              
 25479 steve    20   0  867m 239m  19m S   38 12.1 411:00.43 chromium-browse    
 1470 steve     20   0  455m  42m  13m S   11  2.1 283:38.59 compiz             
 25207 steve    20   0  529m 101m  29m S    7  5.1  29:39.81 chromium-browse    
 2890 steve     20   0  230m  47m  25m S    4  2.4   2:09.85 codeblocks
```

Comment: Try top -H . That shows threads..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's normal if you have a multi-threaded process on a machine with more than one core/thread/processor.

Abstract of [`man top`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top):

> In a true SMP environment, if a process is multi-threaded and top is not operating in Threads mode, amounts greater than 100% may be reported.